# Netbeans, navigate prevoius/next change

Tags: netbeans, navigation, ide

Is there a way to navigate to previous or next change made in the editor...

Something like Visual Studio "Previous" or "Next" arrows

Answer (score 1):

There is `Ctrl+Q` (Last Edit), I'm not sure if there is "next" though

Comment: Works OK,,, and it is ciclic,,, but if know of a way to go "Next" after a few previous please tell us... thanks...

Comment: I think I'll suggest this addition in netbeans features...
if anybody has the same interest please help... I'll leave the link...
https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html